# WebSocketException: WebSocket Connection failed, Server return status code 503, but 101 is expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, websocket

I am trying to connect with C# websocket on Window Server 2019 Standard. But surprisingly if I run normal websocket connection, I got above error message "status code 503 returned, but 101 expected."
I checked IIS version its 10.0+ and websocket protocol is enabled with IIS.
Below is client and server code snippet.

```
`HttpListener httpListener = new HttpListener();
httpListener.Prefixes.Add($"http://127.0.0.1:8085/");
httpListener.Start();
Console.WriteLine("HttpListener started at 127.0.0.1/8085 successfully.");

HttpListenerContext context = await httpListener.GetContextAsync();
if (context.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
{
    HttpListenerWebSocketContext webSocketContext = await context.AcceptWebSocketAsync(subProtocol: null);
    WebSocket webSocket = webSocketContext.WebSocket;
    await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello")),
        WebSocketMessageType.Text,
        true,
        CancellationToken.None);
}`
```

and here is client code.

```
` ClientWebSocket clientWebSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
  await clientWebSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri("ws://127.0.0.1:8085/"), CancellationToken.None);
  byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[2048];
  WebSocketReceiveResult receiveResult = await clientWebSocket.ReceiveAsync(new        ArraySegment<byte>(receiveBuffer),
         CancellationToken.None);
 string receivedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveResult.Count);
 Console.WriteLine(receivedMessage);`
```

but during ConnectAsync call, it always raise exception with message, server return status code 503, but 101 was expected.

I checked IIS configuration and its version. I tried to check solution over net, but no help.

Comment: I don't think IIS can host a console application. Do you accept using asp.net core web application?

Comment: Actually these are 2 simple console application, that is not working on window server, but on normal window machines, websocket connection is fine.

Comment: I can only make this work on web application for IIS.  If without IIS, everything is fine.

Comment: This problem solved, I just need to add 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' as client.Options.AddSubProtocol("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol")